# How can I have arrow of a UIPopOverController on the left side of its top?

Tags: ios, ipad, uipopovercontroller

I have a UIPopover being displayed.
It comes directly under a button with the arrow pointing the button.

This arrow is in the center-aligned on the popover width wise, can I have it slightly towards the top-left corner of the popover ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `UIPopOverController` always centers itself under the UI element you present it from assuming it completely fits. If your button is to the left of the screen and your controller cannot fit under it, only then the controller will be to the right and the arrow would appear on the left side.

Give that, you can play with `popoverLayoutMargins` to set a big margin on the left of the view (if you dont know the exact placement you'll need some trial and error) to move the popover itself to the right and thus the arrow would appear to the left of the top.

I am assuming you are using `presentPopoverFromRect:myRect inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections: UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES`.